# How to disable every sunday in pickadate.js using Woocommerce Easy Booking plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written this code in pickadate-custom.js as shown in documentation but nothing is happening-

```
         $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            weekdaysShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            showMonthsShort: true,
            disable: [0]
         });
```

http://tetralogix.co.in/tastydabbanew/product/veg-thaali/

You can see this link where I am using calendar.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878525/disable-dates-in-pickadate-picker-and-refresh-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker. Disable array of Dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates) - There's a number of times this has been asked, many responses with many different ways of achieving this.

Comment: i have tried but not getting the result

Comment: Have you correctly registered your script? You also need to add before `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`…